Why is it difficult to take the variance of ratios?
I posted a question yesterday (Help using the delta method) on how to derive the variance for the ratio of two random variables:
$$\text{Var}(\frac{X}{Y}) \approx \frac{\text{Var}(X)}{\mu_Y^2} + \frac{\mu_X^2\text{Var}(Y)}{\mu_Y^4} - \frac{2\mu_X\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\mu_Y^3}$$
I have heard people say that the variance of two random variables tends to be unstable (compared to the individual variances of the random variables used in the ratio). I am trying to figure out why this is.
I thought that I could first explore the causes of instability by looking at the partial derivatives of the above expression:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu_Y}Var(\frac{X}{Y}) = -\frac{2}{\mu_Y^3}\sigma_X^2 - \frac{4\mu_X^2}{\mu_Y^5}\sigma_Y^2 + \frac{6\mu_X}{\mu_Y^4}\sigma_{XY}$$
Informally, looking at the terms in the denominator with large exponents, we can see that small changes in the average of $y$ have the ability to create large changes in the overall variance. Specifically, when terms in the denominator are between $0$ and $1$, these can result in large increases of the variance.
The same problem of instability should also happen in sampling I think. If we take samples and the average $y$ is large or small, this will also result in variance instability.
Is this the correct reasoning for understanding why the variance of the ratio for two random variables is said to be unstable?

Simulation : Sample variance vs variance of ratios (note: coefficient of variation is the ratio of sample variance to sample mean) - notice how the ratio estimators (mean and variance) significantly deviate from their true values and display more variation (i.e. higher instability) within the simulations:
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

mu_x <- 10
mu_y <- 10
var_x <- 4
var_y <- 3
cov_xy <- 2

sigma <- matrix(c(var_x, cov_xy, cov_xy, var_y), ncol=2)

true_var_x_div_y <- var_x/(mu_y^2) + (mu_x^2 * var_y)/(mu_y^4) - (2*mu_x*cov_xy)/(mu_y^3)
true_var_y_div_x <- var_y/(mu_x^2) + (mu_y^2 * var_x)/(mu_x^4) - (2*mu_y*cov_xy)/(mu_x^3)

calc_stats <- function(n) {
    sample <- MASS::mvrnorm(n, c(mu_x, mu_y), sigma)
    data.frame(
        var_x = var(sample[,1]),
        var_y = var(sample[,2]),
        var_x_div_y = var(sample[,1] / sample[,2]),
        var_y_div_x = var(sample[,2] / sample[,1]),
        mean_x = mean(sample[,1]),
        mean_y = mean(sample[,2]),
        mean_x_div_y = mean(sample[,1] / sample[,2]),
        mean_y_div_x = mean(sample[,2] / sample[,1])
    )
}

n_reps <- 100
sample_sizes <- 2:100
results <- data.frame()

for(n in sample_sizes) {
    temp_results <- do.call(rbind, replicate(n_reps, calc_stats(n), simplify=FALSE))
    temp_results$sample_size <- n
    results <- rbind(results, temp_results)
}

# Process variance results
results_processed_var <- results %>%
    pivot_longer(
        cols = c(var_x, var_y, var_x_div_y, var_y_div_x),
        names_to = "statistic",
        values_to = "value"
    ) %>%
    group_by(statistic, sample_size) %>%
    summarise(
        mean_value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),
        se = sd(value, na.rm = TRUE) / sqrt(n()),
        ci_lower = mean_value - 1.96 * se,
        ci_upper = mean_value + 1.96 * se,
        .groups = 'drop'
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        statistic = factor(statistic,
                          levels = c("var_x", "var_y", "var_x_div_y", "var_y_div_x"),
                          labels = c("Var(X)", "Var(Y)", "Var(X/Y)", "Var(Y/X)")
        )
    )

# Process means results
results_processed_mean <- results %>%
    pivot_longer(
        cols = c(mean_x, mean_y, mean_x_div_y, mean_y_div_x),
        names_to = "statistic",
        values_to = "value"
    ) %>%
    group_by(statistic, sample_size) %>%
    summarise(
        mean_value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),
        se = sd(value, na.rm = TRUE) / sqrt(n()),
        ci_lower = mean_value - 1.96 * se,
        ci_upper = mean_value + 1.96 * se,
        .groups = 'drop'
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        statistic = factor(statistic,
                          levels = c("mean_x", "mean_y", "mean_x_div_y", "mean_y_div_x"),
                          labels = c("Mean(X)", "Mean(Y)", "Mean(X/Y)", "Mean(Y/X)")
        )
    )

# Reference lines for variances
ref_lines_var <- data.frame(
    statistic = c("Var(X)", "Var(Y)", "Var(X/Y)", "Var(Y/X)"),
    true_value = c(var_x, var_y, true_var_x_div_y, true_var_y_div_x)
)

# Reference lines for means
ref_lines_mean <- data.frame(
    statistic = c("Mean(X)", "Mean(Y)", "Mean(X/Y)", "Mean(Y/X)"),
    true_value = c(mu_x, mu_y, mu_x/mu_y, mu_y/mu_x)
)

# Plot for variances
p_var <- ggplot(results_processed_var, aes(x = sample_size)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = mean_value), color = "blue") +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ci_lower, ymax = ci_upper), alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_hline(data = ref_lines_var, 
               aes(yintercept = true_value), 
               linetype = "dashed", 
               color = "red") +
    facet_wrap(~statistic, scales = "free_y") +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(
        x = "Sample Size",
        y = "Value",
        title = "Sample Variances vs Sample Size with 95% Confidence Intervals",
        subtitle = paste(n_reps, "repetitions per sample size\nRed lines show true values (delta method for ratios)")
    ) +
    theme(
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
    )

# Plot for means
p_mean <- ggplot(results_processed_mean, aes(x = sample_size)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = mean_value), color = "blue") +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ci_lower, ymax = ci_upper), alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_hline(data = ref_lines_mean, 
               aes(yintercept = true_value), 
               linetype = "dashed", 
               color = "red") +
    facet_wrap(~statistic, scales = "free_y") +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(
        x = "Sample Size",
        y = "Value",
        title = "Sample Means vs Sample Size with 95% Confidence Intervals",
        subtitle = paste(n_reps, "repetitions per sample size\nRed lines show true values")
    ) +
    theme(
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
    )

# Display both plots
print(p_var)
print(p_mean)

# Calculate stability metrics for both variance and means
stability_metrics <- results %>%
    pivot_longer(
        cols = c(var_x, var_y, var_x_div_y, var_y_div_x),
        names_to = "statistic",
        values_to = "value"
    ) %>%
    group_by(statistic, sample_size) %>%
    summarise(
        mean_value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),
        sd_value = sd(value, na.rm = TRUE),
        cv = sd_value / abs(mean_value),
        iqr = IQR(value, na.rm = TRUE),
        rel_iqr = iqr / abs(mean_value),
        .groups = 'drop'
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        statistic = factor(statistic,
                          levels = c("var_x", "var_y", "var_x_div_y", "var_y_div_x"),
                          labels = c("Var(X)", "Var(Y)", "Var(X/Y)", "Var(Y/X)")
        )
    )

p_stability <- ggplot(stability_metrics, aes(x = sample_size, y = cv, color = statistic)) +
    geom_line() +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(
        x = "Sample Size",
        y = "Coefficient of Variation",
        title = "Coefficient of Variation vs Sample Size",
        color = "Statistic"
    ) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")

print(p_stability)





A plain (evident) answer to your title : a ratio gives rise, when the denominator is close to $0$, to "far away outlayers" polluting the whole process.
